# Select Where Count() of multiple columns is greater than one

Tags: mysql, count

Say I have data like this:

```
ClaimID ClaimLine    Date
   1        1     22/06/2016
   1        1     01/01/2016
   2        1     08/06/2016
   2        2     31/01/2015
   3        1     23/03/2013
```

How would I select the duplicate ClaimIDs and ClaimLine with the lowest date?

So the return value would be

```
1,1,01/01/2016
```

Comment: You want only the lowest date? Or do you want all lines except the newest date (in case there are more than 2 rows?). That would be something different.

Comment: First, you'd fix your dates to use a date data type.

Comment: I know, I'm actually using an INT to do Min on but I just chose date because i thought it would be easier to understand

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can group by the columns you want to deduplicate, and select the minimum date from each group:

```
SELECT ClaimID, ClaimLine, MIN(Date)
FROM Table
GROUP BY ClaimID, ClaimLine
ORDER BY ClaimID, ClaimLine
```

If you further only want to see the ClaimIDs and ClaimLines that have been duplicated, you can add a HAVING clause:

```
SELECT ClaimID, ClaimLine, MIN(Date)
FROM Table
GROUP BY ClaimID, ClaimLine
HAVING COUNT(*) > 1
ORDER BY ClaimID, ClaimLine
```

Comment: Thank you, I was getting really confused when I was trying it as I was Grouping ClaimID and ClaimLine like so: GROUP BY ClaimID AND ClaimLine and it was only bringing back one record.

Comment: @AndrewKilburn keep in mind, if there are other fields you are are selecting and will not be grouping on but did not mention, the values you get will not be necessarily from the row that has the `MIN(Date)`.